# recordEditForm not loading related record via lookup

Tags: lightning, lightning-recordeditform

I have the exact same component in 2 different sandboxes.  The component uses `lightning:recordEditForm` and is passed an object name & Id.  There is a lookup field to the Account object that is supposed to display as an output field in the form.  I'm getting 2 different outcomes on page load..

Org A: When the component's `recordEditForm` loads, the Account loads and the __r related record also loads.  I can see this by debugging the event params onload of the form, like this

[image]

Org B: The exact same component, in the exact same context, loads the Account field, but DOES NOT load the __r related record.  So what I'm left with is a blank output on the Account field in the UI.

[image]

As you can see, the __r JSON does not load, so the form doesn't display the Account Name in the form.

I'm a sys admin in both orgs, with Modify All & CRUD access to Account object & the base object I'm working with - so it's not FLS or anything like that.  Can anyone help explain why this would load in one context but not another?

EDIT for more context:
Also in looking at what the `recordEditForm` is loading, I can see the objectInfos is not loading the Account object either..

Org A:

[image]

vs Org B:

[image]

Again - I have full read/write/modify all access to all objects & fields in both orgs...

Comment: What's the difference between ORG A and ORG B? Was one more recently refreshed, is work done primarily first in one over the other, etc.

Comment: Few questions just to eliminate some possibilities: do the components have same API version in both orgs ? and do the fields loaded within the component, have data in them in org B ?

Comment: it's a shortcoming of the documentation.  they fail to mention Field Accessibility anywhere in the docs.  See the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I figured this out.  recordEditForm upholds not only FLS, but also "Field Accessibility".  So in this case the standard Page Layout for the record I was editing did not have the Account field on it.  Therefore the recordEditForm would not load the field's data.

[image]

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation) mentions nothing about accessibility, only FLS.

> "This component also takes care of field-level security and sharing for you, so users see only the data they have access to."

I consider this field accessibility restraint a bug more than a feature...

Comment: +1. This is a good information. I think this could be either a bug or missed documentation. Good to highlight this to Salesforce.

Comment: @JayantDas the behavior is indeed strange but there exist an article documenting this, refer to my answer

Comment: @Shamina That is definitely the issue here. Thanks for pointing out that in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the link to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000349125&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) which mentions this:

> When using Lookup Field in lightning:recordEditForm, the field value may not show the existing data. This is because the
>   lightning:inputField is currently populated only when the field is
>   added to Page Layout.

Comment: Thanks @Shamina.  I'm still convinced that this information should be included in the actual documentation for the component and not in a knowledge article.